# How to restrict attributes in attributeGroup?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have this `attributeGroup`:

```
<attributeGroup name="date">
  <attribute name="year" type="int"/>
  <attribute name="month" type="int"/>
  <attribute name="day" type="int"/>
</attributeGroup>
```

and I want make a restriction on each attribute:

- year has to be 1900~2020
- month has to be 01~12
- day has to be 01~31

For example,

```
<releaseDate year="2013" month="12" day="11"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xs:minInclusive` and `xs:maxInclusive` via `xs:restriction`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:attributeGroup name="dateAttrGroup">
    <xs:attribute name="year">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1900"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="2020"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="month">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="12"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="day">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="31"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:element name="releaseDate">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="dateAttrGroup"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```